# indent keywords or a specific selection of lines in vim

Tags: vim

How do you indent a specific selection of lines in vim, for example line 1, 5 and 6.

Also is their a way to indent lines begining with a certain keyword. For example search for all words begining with def and indent it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To indent line 7

```
 :7 >>
```

To indent the range of lines 3-5 (indents lines 3,4 and 5)

```
:3,5 >>
```

Search for def and indent **all** matches use the global command g:

```
:g /def/ >>
```

Comment: So there is no way to specify a selection of lines to indent using one command? Also searching for def only indents the first search result.

Comment: @HashTables how about writing a little function, receiving string like `2,3,8,10` then loop through the list to indent?

Comment: I just wanted to mention that you need `:g` (which is a command, not an operator BTW), but you've justed edited that in.

Answer (score 1):

To indent line 1, 5 and 6, you can concatenate multiple `:>>` commands in a single command-line:

```
:1>>|5,6>>
```

The `:global` command allows to indent (the same applies to all other Ex commands, too) only lines matching a pattern.

```
:g/def/>>
```

Comment: I tried using `:g/def/>%` to indent blocks of code (`>%` seems to work fine, when I have cursor over `def`). How can I use motion in that command?

Comment: `>` (vs. `:>>`) is a _normal mode_ command; you need to use `:g/def/normal >%`. Note that the cursor is positioned on the start of the line, but that should work for `def`, right?

Comment: For me `:g/def/>` works with Vim defaults, and `:>>` indents twice.